# Imprimir JSON formatado usando PHP

Tags: php, json

Estou com o seguinte código:

```
<?php

    $arquivo = scandir("Arquivo");

    $data = array();

    foreach ($arquivo as $img) {
        if (!in_array($img, array(".",".."))) {

            $filename = "Arquivo" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $img;

            $info = pathinfo($filename);

            $info["size"] = filesize($filename);

            array_push($data, $info);

        }   
}


echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

E não consigo imprimir o JSON com quebra de lina, as informações ficam lado a lado.

[Imagem de como o código está saindo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syKJF.jpg)

Na imagem em anexo mostra como esta saindo a informação e na imagem também tem um bloco de notas mostrando como preciso que a informação seja impressa.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` do PHP para isso ou enviar um Content-Type adequado, para que no navegador interprete o JSON e possa "formata-lo". Mas, lembre-se que ambos os JSONs (com ou sem "quebra de linha") são idênticos e são tratados da mesma maneira.

**1. Content-Type:**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 

echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); // Provável que em 99% dos navegadores usar o json_encode($data) ficará formatado também, devido ao header acima.
```

---

**2. HTML:**

> Nota: isto não será um JSON válido!

```
echo "<pre>" . json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . "</pre>"
```

Escolha uma das opções que melhor se encaixam no seu caso de uso.